# Quartz cluster: how to config that when the scheduler start,the scheduler load configeration from job store?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, quartz

I want to use the configuration from `jobstore` when I restart the `Quarz` scheduler.
I do not want the primary configuration to overwrite the one that is already in `jobstore`, such as the `cron_trigger` configration.

How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: i want to use the configuration data which in job store when i restart the Quarz cluster. the detail is : when i first start   scheduler in quarz cluster, the data of trigger store in the database. Then i may change the data of trigger in the database such as cron, When i restart the scheduler, the sheduler will load the configuration from database,not use that in the codes,in other words, when i restart scheduler , the sheduler config do not overwrite that in database.